# When I commit an array of objects to a Vuex store, the objects lose one of their properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a Vuex action that makes a GET request to the back-end and gets all the servers of a user as a response:

```
    async getUserServers({commit, state, dispatch}, userId){
        try {
            let response = await axios.get("/servers/" + userId)
            let servers = response.data.servers
            console.log(servers)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

With the code as it is, I can `console.log(servers)` and navigate the properties right down to `servers[0].rooms[0].messages[0].user` and access the user property which contains this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "username": "Test",
  "email": "test@abv.bg",
  "image": "test.png",
  "createdAt": "2020-08-12T21:09:58.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-08-12T21:09:58.000Z"
}
```

My problem arises as soon as I try to commit the servers to my Vuex store. When I do this:

```
    async getUserServers({commit, state, dispatch}, userId){
        try {
            let response = await axios.get("/servers/" + userId)
            let servers = response.data.servers
            console.log(servers)
            commit('setServers', servers)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

This mutation gets executed:

```
    setServers(state, servers){
        state.servers = servers
    }
```

Now when I check my Vuex state through the Vue.js developer tool, I can see that the `user` property of `servers[0].rooms[0].messages[0]` doesn't exists and I can't figure out why is it disappearing. Every property of the object is fine except this one.

Comment: @Bobumaru is `messages` field is initialized with empty array / string or it is undefined ?

Comment: @KrzysztofKaczyński Messages is defined and it's an array of message objects. The problem is that the messages objects are missing the user property which contains a user object of whomever posted the message.

Comment: Can you share a reproduction in Codesandbox?

Comment: @tony19 is right if you want help provide more information please

Comment: @tony19 I used Codesandbox to create e reproduction, however, in there I don't encounter the issue which confuses me even more. So it's kinda pointless to send the reproduction as it doesn't show the problem I'm encountering but at the same time the problem persists on my actual project. I guess something is happening somewhere in my project but I can't even figure out where to start from.